# cant reach for loop with while loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Even tho I searched a lot in here for the while loop, still cant find my problem!

```
    mylist = []

user_choice = input(' 1: Make a list\n 2: Delete a list\n 3: Delete elements from a list\n 4: Quit\n ')

while user_choice == '1':
    first_input = input('Type your list elements: ')
    mylist.append(first_input)
    if len(mylist) == 5:
        user_choice = input(' 1: Delete a list\n 2: Delete elements from a list\n 3: Quit\n ')
        if user_choice == 3:
           break
        elif user_choice == 1:
            mylist.clear()
        elif user_choice == 2:
            print('Which element you want to delete? ')
            print(mylist)
```

That is my code.

When code reaches at 'if user_choice == 3' and below, I keep getting the while loop back, while I want to get the if user choices instead!

User press then '1' KEY BUTTON, it gets to enter his list elements then it appends the in the list. While my list reaches 5 elements, it prompts the user to choose if he wants to delete the list or the elements from a list with pop() (didnt reached that yet) and last if he wants to quit. While I press '1' to delete the list, it gets me back to while loop printing 'Type your list elements'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `input` returns a string.

Comment: How do you plan to exit the flow? At what point does it stop and returns your list.

Comment: somewhere in the bottom with another while and break.

Do you recommend a way of exiting? If yes, please tell me.

Comment: I added my answer, let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your `user_choice` does not get updated once your elements reach 5 that is why it does it stuck in your inner loop.

See if this works for you:

```
l = []
choice = int(input('choice? 1- add, 2- remove, 3- exit '))
while True:
    if choice == 1:
        if len(l) < 5:
            l.append(input('new input '))
            print(l)
            choice = int(input('choice? '))
        else:
            print('list is full ')
            choice = int(input('2- remove or 3-exit '))
    elif choice == 2:
        if not l:
            print('list is empty')
            choice = int(input('choice? 1- add, 2- remove, 3- exit '))
        try:
            l.remove(input('remove? '))
        except ValueError:
            print('No such value ')
        choice = int(input('choice? '))
    elif choice == 3:
        break
```

It is pretty wordy due to how it was before, basically, it allows you to enter a new choice unless you want to quit. It checks if the list has less than 5 elements before it allows you to append, else it just prints `'list is full'` and goes back to prompting for a new choice.

Similar to if you want to remove items, it checks if the list has elements. If the list is empty it will print `list is empty` and prompts for a new choice. Similarly, if the value is not in the list, it prints `value not found` and prompts for a new choice.

Finally exiting just breaks the whole loop.

Comment: You might also want to take note here that it does not make sure that your inputs are within boundaries, 1 to 3. You might want to add a helper function for that. Lastly, if you find that this answer solved your question you can help others by adding clicking the check box below the arrows!

Comment: I will admit it was pretty usefull and helpfull, tho I am trying to do something else, even though this helped me a lot figuring out how while works. Thank you BernardL.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using Python 2. There, input() evaluates the input. Thus, you cannot compare to the char '1' but need to use the Integer 1:

```
while user_choice == 1:
    ...
```

And the first_input takes one element at a time. So to fill up the list with 5 elements, you have to do five inputs.

Comment: This does not explicitly solve the question. And the while is clearly shown to be compared to string type and not int.